# Navigation Bar title change

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uinavigationbar

I want to change the Navigation bar title of the second view controller to show the name of a "var wordNames" (Array of words), I got an error "Value of type '[String]' has no member 'string'" happens the same if I change to title = wordNames.text

```
title = wordNames.string
```

Any help is more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordNames is an array.
You need to use subscript.
    wordNames[0]

Comment: Hi Jason thank you for the reply, I need to search for this, have no idea how to use on this example :(

Comment: How did you declare the wordNames variable and what kind of information is stored in that variable?